# How to connect two HA group containers in Bluemix?

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

Our team has developed an application that runs on 3 diferent containers: a web deployment, a rest service and a cassandra db.

We have tested it on 3 single containers run like this:

```
cf ic run --name rest -p <port>:<port> --link cassandra:cassandra -d <DOMAIN>/rest
```

Same for web and a bit different for cassandra, and it works.

But we are unable to link it the same way using **scalable container**.

In what way can we deploy two scalable container groups (web and rest) that link to a third one (cassandra)?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way would be to use something like https://www.amalgam8.io/ and deploy the sidecar pointing to the private ip of the group's load balancer.  That way it would stay updated as you rollout new versions of the group (without having to redeploy the other related groups).